# slicing multi d array ,problem with index

Tags: python, numpy

i am runnig this line

```
 event_probs=np.asarray( 
 self.all_results_probabilities_smoothed[start_frame_num:end_frame_number])[:,0]
```

and this is the print , of this line

```
ndarray: [array([0.99221474, 0.02794698, 0.01088856], dtype=float32)
array([0.99584645, 0.03152211, 0.08942476], dtype=float32)
array([0.9955728 , 0.02596352, 0.26252457], dtype=float32)
array([0.99848574, 0.03096167, 0.83289665], dtype=float32)
array([0.9988594 , 0.02529432, 0.93383425], dtype=float32)
array([0.9988399 , 0.02355683, 0.96631527], dtype=float32)
array([0.99924624, 0.03478203, 0.99265254], dtype=float32)
array([0.99880326, 0.03510844, 0.9966635 ], dtype=float32)
array([0.99914837, 0.02710808, 0.9968749 ], dtype=float32)
array([0.9986891 , 0.02977812, 0.9965431 ], dtype=float32)
array([0.9985268 , 0.04807042, 0.99733377], dtype=float32)
array([0.9950269 , 0.03662388, 0.9988675 ], dtype=float32)
array([0.98378396, 0.04183222, 0.9989925 ], dtype=float32)
array([0.9758868 , 0.07405277, 0.9994506 ], dtype=float32)
array([0.9407065 , 0.36036757, 0.9992743 ], dtype=float32)
array([0.925014  , 0.45132786, 0.99823976], dtype=float32)
array([0.89381886, 0.77280957,...
```

i need to change the code , that i will get the first element of each array for all the array

the array of self.all_results_probabilities_smoothed[start_frame_num:end_frame_number]
look like this

```
 ndarray: [[array([0.99221474, 0.02794698, 0.01088856], dtype=float32) 766]
 [array([0.99584645, 0.03152211, 0.08942476], dtype=float32) 767]
 [array([0.9955728 , 0.02596352, 0.26252457], dtype=float32) 768]
 [array([0.99848574, 0.03096167, 0.83289665], dtype=float32) 769]
[array([0.9988594 , 0.02529432, 0.93383425], dtype=float32) 770]
[array([0.9988399 , 0.02355683, 0.96631527], dtype=float32) 771]
[array([0.99924624, 0.03478203, 0.99265254], dtype=float32) 772]
[array([0.99880326, 0.03510844, 0.9966635 ], dtype=float32) 773]
[array([0.99914837, 0.02710808, 0.9968749 ], dtype=float32) 774]
[array([0.9986891 , 0.02977812, 0.9965431 ], dtype=float32) 775]
[array([0.9985268 , 0.04807042, 0.99733377], dtype=float32) 776]
[array([0.9950269 , 0.03662388, 0.9988675 ], dtype=float32) 777]
[array([0.98378396, 0.04183222, 0.9989925 ], dtype=float32) 778]
[array([0.9758868 , 0.07405277, 0.9994506 ], dtype=float32) 779]
[array([0.9407065 , 0.36036757, 0.9992743 ], dtype=float32) 780]
```

thanks for the help

Comment: What is the problem?  Is the *print* an example of the input or the result of the slice? If it is the result of the slice, please post a minimal example of the *input* and the expected result.

Comment: thanks for the comment i change it

Comment: How do you know `self.all_results_probabilities_smoothed[start_frame_num:end_frame_number]` is a numpy array? What you have shown looks like a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the multi array and get individual array and get the first element sample code

`for i in your_multi_dim_arra:
               c=i[0]`

Or you can use slicing

`your_multi_dim_arr[:, 0]`
Sorry I forgot slicing btw
Which means you’re selecting all the rows and inside that choose the 0 th index element if you use -1 it means right most index value

Comment: there is no a option of using slicing ? because to do loop is very expensive and slicing is very fast.

Comment: It’s a multi dimensional array of course you can use slicing I forgot that tbh

Comment: when i am doing it , i get a error too many indices for array

Comment: Can you give show me the sample code that you’ve tried? And if you can please print the shape of it buy using event_probs.shape()

Comment: print(event_prob.shape)
(17,)

Comment: Okay which means you don’t have a multidimensional array try reshape it to 2 dimensional array array.reshape((array.reshape[0],1))

Comment: then you have no other way than sticking to the basic for loop iteration.

Comment: but the shape of the first array is np.asarray(self.all_results_probabilities_smoothed[start_frame_num:end_frame_number]).shape
(17, 2)

Comment: when i am add this [:, 0] i get (17,) before is (17,2)

Comment: `from numpy import * x = range(34)
x = reshape(x,(17,2))
x[:, 0]
#output x[:,0]
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32])
#output x
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [18, 19],
       [20, 21],
       [22, 23],
       [24, 25],
       [26, 27],
       [28, 29],
       [30, 31],
       [32, 33]])
`
as you can see i have created a (17,2) array and choose 0 th element

Comment: if i am duing that np.asarray(self.all_results_probabilities_smoothed[start_frame_num:end_frame_number])[:,0][0] , i get array([0.99221474, 0.02794698, 0.01088856], dtype=float32) , and if i am coding this np.asarray(self.all_results_probabilities_smoothed[start_frame_num:end_frame_number])[:,0][0][0] i am getting 0.99221474

Comment: the shape of the array is  bit odd to me it has to be 3 dimensional array because inside individual element is has a array

Answer (score 0):

You can slice it using numpy's way of indexing/slicing multidimensional arrays

```
>>> a=np.array([[3,2,1],[4,5,6],[9,8,7],[10,11,12]])
>>> a
array([[ 3,  2,  1],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 9,  8,  7],
       [10, 11, 12]])
>>> a[:,0]
array([ 3,  4,  9, 10])
```

Meaning of the index

```
#   array name [  all rows  ,  column index ]    
>>> a          [  :         ,  0            ]
```

Comment: when i am doing it , i  get a error too many indices for array

Comment: Probably you have problems with the previous operation with frames, not with slicing...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've generated a 2d array containing arrays and numbers.  I can create something like that with:

```
In [191]: arr = np.array([(np.random.randint(0,10,3),np.random.randint(0,10,1)[0]) for _ in range(5)])                                                
In [192]: arr                                                                   
Out[192]: 
array([[array([8, 3, 6]), 5],
       [array([2, 2, 5]), 7],
       [array([1, 1, 4]), 9],
       [array([9, 2, 2]), 2],
       [array([6, 8, 2]), 8]], dtype=object)
```

Check the dtype and shape:

```
In [193]: arr.dtype                                                             
Out[193]: dtype('O')
In [194]: arr.shape                                                             
Out[194]: (5, 2)
```

The number column:

```
In [195]: arr[:,1]                                                              
Out[195]: array([5, 7, 9, 2, 8], dtype=object)
```

The array column, which you've already found:

```
In [196]: arr[:,0]                                                              
Out[196]: 
array([array([8, 3, 6]), array([2, 2, 5]), array([1, 1, 4]),
       array([9, 2, 2]), array([6, 8, 2])], dtype=object)
```

If all those arrays have the same shape, they can be joined into one array:

```
In [197]: np.stack(arr[:,0])                                                    
Out[197]: 
array([[8, 3, 6],
       [2, 2, 5],
       [1, 1, 4],
       [9, 2, 2],
       [6, 8, 2]])
```

which we can then index as before:

```
In [198]: np.stack(arr[:,0])[:,0]                                               
Out[198]: array([8, 2, 1, 9, 6])
```

If the subarrays vary in shape, we'd have to use a list comprehension to fetch the first element of each.